# Is it safe to replace ethernet wall plate with a camera?

Tags: drywall, low-voltage, ethernet

I want to mount a camera horizontally with no wires showing. I thought it might be easiest if I just covered the ethernet wall plate with the power over ethernet camera. This would completely cover the hole in the wall, but there would be a small gap (2-3mm maybe) between the camera and the wall. Since it is a low voltage wire, I'm tempted to think it doesn't violate electrical codes. Would it violate building or fire codes?

Answer (score 1):

It would not violate NEC code. There is no box required for communications cable like cat 5-6. Putting a device that covers the hole even 100% covered is fine.